# One liner for batch changes in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace

I have a pandas dataframe, with 10 columns and thousands of rows.
The first column is the name of website users, for example:

```
  Name ...
0 Alex
1 Fred
2 John
3 Chloe
...
```

I want to change this first column into this:

```
  Name ...
0 Hi! Alex, mind calling me at 8 p.m.?
1 Hi! Fred, mind calling me at 8 p.m.?
2 Hi! John, mind calling me at 8 p.m.?
3 Hi! Chloe, mind calling me at 8 p.m.?
...
```

Here, the number 8 will be free input.

In a word, the target string template might be: `"Hi! {}, mind calling me at {} p.m.?"` - The first placeholder will be the word in the corresponding cell, and the second one for the input number.

I thought of iterating over all rows and manually change the string, but this looks awful and non-pythonian way.

I would like to know if there is a one-liner to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want use template is necessary loop in `apply` or `map` like:

```
y = 8
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: f"Hi! {x}, mind calling me at {y} p.m.?")
#alternative
#df['Name'] = df['Name'].map(lambda x: f"Hi! {x}, mind calling me at {y} p.m.?")
print (df)
                                    Name
0   Hi! Alex, mind calling me at 8 p.m.?
1   Hi! Fred, mind calling me at 8 p.m.?
2   Hi! John, mind calling me at 8 p.m.?
3  Hi! Chloe, mind calling me at 8 p.m.?
```

No `apply` alternative:

```
y = 8
df['Name'] = "Hi! " + df['Name'] + ", mind calling me at " + str(y) + "p.m.?"
print (df)
                                   Name
0   Hi! Alex, mind calling me at 8p.m.?
1   Hi! Fred, mind calling me at 8p.m.?
2   Hi! John, mind calling me at 8p.m.?
3  Hi! Chloe, mind calling me at 8p.m.?
```

Comment: Thanks, @jezarel. May I ask which is the fastest way? I have to do this very often and with vast amount of data.

Comment: @Nikita - I think second solution should be faster.